# Getting from $m^2 + n^2 + p^2 = mnp + 4$ to $(m + n + p + 2)^2 = (m + 2)(n + 2)(p + 2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

$$m^2 + n^2 + p^2 = mnp + 4 \tag1$$

Adding $2(mn + np + pm)$ to both sides yields

$$(m + n + p)^2 = mnp + 2(mn + np + pm) + 4 \tag{2}$$

Adding now $4(m + n + p) + 4$ to both sides gives
$$(m + n + p + 2)^2 = (m + 2)(n + 2)(p + 2) \tag{3}$$

I just want an explanation for $(3)$. Can it be verified by expanding?
Is there another way of arriving at that last statement?

Also a link to similar questions is also welcome.

Comment: @Moo Exactly. Is it wrong?

Comment: Doesn't look right.

Comment: @Moo There's a constraint that $m^2+n^2+p^2 = mnp+4$ .

Comment: @Ak.: Thanks, I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align}((m+n+p)+2)^2 &= (m+n+p)^2 + 4(m+n+p) + 4 \\
&= mnp + 2(mn+np+pm)+4(m+n+p) + 8\\
& = (mnp + 2mn)+(2np+4n) + (4p+8) + (4m+2pm) \\
&=mn(p+2)+2n(p+2)+4(p+2)+2m(p+2)\\
&=(p+2)(2m+mn+2n+4)\\
& = (p+2)(2m(n+2)+2(n+2))\\
&=(m+2)(n+2)(p+2)\end{align}$

<sub>In the second line, $(m+n+p)^2= mnp+2(m+n+p)+4$ is used.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what was needed.